# QWebView not loading after opening pop up window

Tags: python, popup, pyqt, qwebview, qwebpage

I am loading an url of a website that allows me to create some data and save it to a database to my QWebView. At first I could save the data but couldn't open the pop-up windows. So I reimplemented QWebView.createWindow() method. Now I am able open the pop-up windows. But after opening a pop-up my webview loses its ability to save data to the database. After I push the save button it doesn't load or reload. What am I doing wrong? Here is my code:

```
class MyWebView(QWebView):
    def __init__(self):
        QWebView.__init__(self)
        self.page().windowCloseRequested.connect(self.closeWindow)
        self.page().settings().setAttribute(QWebSettings.JavaEnabled, True)
        self.page().settings().setAttribute(QWebSettings.JavascriptEnabled, True)
        self.page().settings().setAttribute(QWebSettings.JavascriptCanOpenWindows, True)
        self.page().settings().setAttribute(QWebSettings.JavascriptCanCloseWindows, True)
        self.page().settings().setAttribute(QWebSettings.JavascriptCanAccessClipboard, True)

    def createWindow(self, webType):
        self.webview = MyWebView()
        if webType == QWebPage.WebModalDialog:
            self.webview.setWindowModality(Qt.ApplicationModal)
        return self.webview

    def closeWindow(self):
        self.close()
```